# Double baking monitoring

Tags: baking

What’s the best way to monitor/alarm on double baking? If a professional baker wanted to set up alarms/paging, is there an alternative to setting up your own tzscan instance and check with a cron job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Kiln is a open-source Bake-monitor solution.

*Kiln alerts users if a Monitored Node:*

1.Is on the wrong network

2.Is not on the fittest branch

3.Falls behind the current head block level

4.Cannot be reached by the Monitoring Software (e.g. is offline)

5.Reports fewer than a specified number of active peer connections

6.When a Tezos update is available

*Or if a Monitored Baker:*

**Misses a baking or endorsing opportunity**

Has been deactivated due to inactivity or will be within one cycle

**It also has a notification service in-build:**

> To conifgure Telegram notifications: Click Settings from the left
> panel then click Connect Telegram and follow the instructions in the popup.
>
> To configure e-mail notifications: Click Settings from the left panel and
> provide the SMTP configuration for your SMTP server in the form under
> Email. Add an email address to receive alerts and click Save Settings.

Source: https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/tezos-bake-monitor/blob/develop/README.md